# What's causing this?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I don't understand "why" SQLiteDB may not respond to "-checkIfDatabaseExists".  What's causing this and how do I fix it?  (I'm real close to getting this to work, but because I'm a newbie, I am still having problems).

I appreciate any assistance I can get on this.  Here is the code:

```
#import "SQLiteDB.h"

static SQLiteDB *sharedSQLiteDB = nil;  //  makes this a singleton class

@implementation SQLiteDB

@synthesize db, dbPath, databaseKey;


//--------------    check for database or create it    ----------------|
#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (SQLiteDB *) sharedSQLiteDB  {

    if(!sharedSQLiteDB)  {
        sharedSQLiteDB = [[SQLiteDB alloc] init];
        [sharedSQLiteDB checkIfDatabaseExists];
    }
    return sharedSQLiteDB;
}   

+(id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone  {
    if(!sharedSQLiteDB)  {
        sharedSQLiteDB = [super allocWithZone:zone];
        return  sharedSQLiteDB;
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}   

-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone  {
    return self;
}

-(void) release  {
    //  no-op
}


- (void) checkIfDatabaseExists  {
    // Get the path to the database file
    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ppcipher.s3db"];

    // Open the database file
    const char *cDatabasePath = [databasePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if(sqlite3_open(cDatabasePath, &db) == SQLITE_OK)  //  does it exist?
        return;
    else {  //  create database file here

    }

}
@end
```

[image: Here is the results of the build:]

Comment: Please paste code as text, not just a screenshot.

Comment: Of course.... why bother with writing yet another database wrapper (if that is what you are doing)?   Core Data is the best supported and best performing (without monumental engineering effort) way to create databases on iOS / Mac OS X.  If you need to wrap a SQLite database of arbitrary schema, FMDB seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about what you've implemented here, but from what I can tell, your header has defined +checkIfDatabaseExists as a class method (although you haven't implemented it yet, hence the "incomplete implementation" and "method definition not found" warnings). However, in your sharedSQLiteDB method, you are calling -checkIfDatabaseExists on an instance of SQLiteDB which refers to a instance method that you have not defined.

Edit: Okay, after seeing the full code, my above answer is obviously not the case. But what does your header look like? Do you have a + instead of a - in front of the checkIfDatabaseExists signature?

Answer (score 0):

When you have:

```
- (void) foo
{
   [self bar];
}

- (void) bar
{ ... }
```

The compiler hasn't seen the definition of `-bar` when compiling `-foo` and, thus, will warn that `self` may not respond to `-bar` when compiling `-foo`.

If that method is intended to be entirely private to the class, then do this at the top of the .m file:

```
@interface Foo()
- (void) bar;
@end
```

If it is intended to be called by other classes, add the method declaration to the `@interface`.